# Is there a way to constantly track one players jumping activity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made these commands

this command sets a ver to count all jumps by all players

```
/scoreboard objectives add didjump stat.jump particular player Jumps
```

this command sets up a var to use as a display

```
/scoreboard objectives add trackjump dummy trackjump
```

this command adds one to each player that has already jumped and puts it in the display var

```
/scoreboard players add @a[score_didjump_min=1] trackjump 1
```

this command only happens in sequence after the above command goes off; it removes the jump from the last count so that the total doesn't increment constantly unless the player is still jumping

```
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_didjump_min=1] didjump 1
```

Then I display that score on the list board when you hold tab, however I ONLY want a specific player to be tracked and am unsure how to write the commands, so far I have tried to modify the @a in the above commands and it then tracks the players name with an @ sign in front of it not the player itself.

Comment: Has replacing just @a with your players name worked?

Comment: No sadly I have tried but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so having slept on it I have a solution. I am going to create a new dummy objective as a flag var and give a value to it for only that player. I will then use this in the test globally

`/scoreboard players add @a[score_thisplayeronly_min=1,score_didjump_min=1] trackjump 1`

and only that player will have the trackjump increased and so it will only display for that player as no one else will have a score in the var.

Comment: That's what I would've done - if you hadn't answered your own question I'd have answered it for you. :)